# how to set NVL on SQL with TO_CHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I trying to set a `nvl()` with the value OPEN on ->

```
        select to_char(max(CLOSE_DATE),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

If it is closed is getting the date ('dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') otherwise it should display OPEN

Any ideas, where I can put correctly the `NVL()`?

Solution:

```
        select nvl (to_char(max(CLOSE_DATE),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OPEN')
```

---

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help a lot. What default do you want to apply?

Comment: the idea is that if no date 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' is available to display a wording like 'still open' instead that the output is empty.
The script is working but i have difficult to set 'still open' in case the date  'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' is not available.. 
script: 
select to_char(max(CLOSE_DATE),'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' from...... as Close_date

Comment: By *the date 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'*, do you mean *the date*? I mean, if it's null it's null, regardless of what format you want to apply. Anyway, sample data would still help.

Comment: yes i mean the date: out put is like this
Product-ID: 55766  
Product-Status: OPEN   
Creation-Date:  11.04.2018 19:26:32
Close-Date: here should be displayed 'still open'

Comment: I meant a detailed example added to your question that we could try out for ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
select decode(close_date, null, 'OPEN', 
                                to_char(close_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
             ) result
from your_table
```

Or

```
select nvl(to_char(close_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OPEN') result
from your_table
```

Comment: Why not simple Standard SQL instead of proprietary syntax? `COALESCE(to_char(close_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'OPEN')`

Comment: Because it is tagged as "Oracle"? Apart from that, no other reason, @dnoeth; thank you for the comment, though.

Comment: thx for all feedbacks, but OPEN doesn't appear field is still empty... in case there is no date. other ideas?